# How can I iterate through the rooms in Socket.IO?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, chatroom

I'm trying to create a list of buttons where each one of them represents an avaialable Room. So when the user clicks a button they will join that room.

My problem is that I cannot find a way to access this data to iterate through it.
When I use `console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms)` I get this:

```js
{
  ZQ6iFbooGw3Dv3xgAAAA: Room { sockets: { ZQ6iFbooGw3Dv3xgAAAA: true }, length: 1 },
  Room1: Room {
    sockets: { ZQ6iFbooGw3Dv3xgAAAA: true, SWBqN3_5Z6ISy4BlAAAB: true },
    length: 2
  },
  SWBqN3_5Z6ISy4BlAAAB: Room { sockets: { SWBqN3_5Z6ISy4BlAAAB: true }, length: 1 }
}
```

There are three rooms, and two users at the same room called "Room1". The first room is "ZQ6iFbooGw3Dv3xgAAAA", thats the ID by default. "Room1" is the second and finally "SWBqN3_5Z6ISy4BlAAAB". Only "Room1" contains both clients, you can see the lenght of 2. The other two rooms only contains their respective user. This rooms are created automatically.

Which brings me to my second problem. Even if I could find a way to iterate this data, how can I separate the rooms created by me and the rooms that are created every time a new client connects to the server?
Because they are stored at the same place. Is there another array I am missing?

Comment: Can't you keep a list of rooms you create, i.e., whenever you create room, add it to the list?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well thats what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: so your question is, how to loop through propertys in an object?

Comment: If you don't want to keep objects around, you could store just the names of the rooms you create. Or create them with some unique, recognizable prefix. Or make sure their names are always shorter than 20 chars (or whatever length is minimum for hashes created for socket names by socket.io).

Comment: Yes, basically. I was trying with foreach but I guess is not how it works. And if you know if this is the only way Socket.io stores the rooms.

Comment: Oh, you can use `Object.keys(io.adapter.rooms)` to get the list of names, or `for (let key in io.adapter.rooms) {}`. Basically any way that allows to iterate over Object's keys in JavaScript.

Comment: Alright. I thought i was missing a function or object inside Socket.io. But if is not the case I'll try that. Thank you for the responses.